# Custom Fields and Events

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having a problem with setting up a dynamic date into my WordPress theme. I installed the `Advanced Custom Fields` plugin to make the custom field for my event posts, I made separate sections outside post and pages for events in `wp-admin`.

I added a new custom field for dates on my `‘events’` and I added manually dates on events which I already created before and to make it dynamic I edited the code in the theme, but dates just don’t want to change according to those ones which I set them to be.

Here is the code, I don’t know what am I doing wrong:

```
$homepagePosts = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
));

while ($homepagePosts->have_posts()) {
    $homepagePosts->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="event-summary">
        <a class="event-summary__date event-summary__date--beige t-center" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <span class="event-summary__month"><?php
                $eventDate = new DateTime(get_field('event_date'));
                echo $eventDate->format('M')
            ?></span>
            <span class="event-summary__day"><?php the_time('d'); ?><?php echo $eventDate->format('d') ?></span>
        </a>
        <div class="event-summary__content">
            <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
            <p><?php if (has_excerpt()) {
                echo get_the_excerpt();
            }
            else {
                echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 18);
            }
            ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="nu gray">Read more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: We need the actual code in a [mcve]. We don't debug images.

Comment: Adding to @j08691, the screenshot host might get removed at some point or could get blocked for certain users. You can format the code in the question. There is a guide on the right side of the screen while editing you question

Comment: I was on my mobile phone, it's fixed now :)

Comment: can you provide how you set up your custom fields?

Comment: @denisey field type: date picker
display format: 12/11/2019
return format: 12/11/2019
rules: post type is equal to Event
active: yes

Comment: Seems like I found a problem, it was inside a plugin... I just changed formats of the dates and now everything seems to work fine :) change it to: display format: custom "Ymd"
Return Format: 20191112 "Ymd"